# React Formik onSubmit Problem Specific To Running Against Build

Tags: reactjs, formik

I have a problem in that my built react app is unable to submit in Formik's onSubmit function.

Running in dev react-scripts start works fine.

It is only when I build the project and try serving the build locally that it fails to submit.

I'm not getting an error as such but I get:-
**Formik.tsx:834 Warning: An unhandled error was caught from submitForm() ReferenceError: _i9 is not defined**

The code line referenced (within onSubmit) in the chrome console is the second one here:-

```
for(let i = 1; i <= values.numberOfTokens; i++) {

                let tokenTypeValue = parseInt(values.tokenTypes[i-1]);
```

I'm not sure why this runs without any warnings / errors in dev yet is failing when running against the built code.

Has anyone come across an issue like this?

values.tokenTypes is initialized in Formik's initialValues like this:-

```
let tokenTypeArray = [1];
    
return(

    <Formik 
        initialValues={{tokenTypes: tokenTypeArray ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else stumbles across this in future as a result of receiving a similar warning, i.e. :-

**Formik.tsx:834 Warning: An unhandled error was caught from submitForm() ReferenceError: xx is not defined**

I managed to work out the issue and fix this myself by taking the let i=1 declaration outside of the for declaration.

Not 100% sure why but by using chrome console and adding a breakpoint on to the thrown exception line, I was able to see that the i was variable being viewed as undefined in the build formik js.

By placing the declaration outside, the build subsequently worked:-

```
let i = 1;
            for(i = 1; i <= values.numberOfTokens; i++) {
                
                let tokenTypeValue = parseInt(values.tokenTypes[i-1]);
```

Hope this might help point someone in the right direct in future...